# using nth-child and has

Tags: jquery

I need to have the 14th `td` in a `tbody` > `tr` row that contains a `input` `checkbox` that is checked to add a class to that parent `td`. I am sure I am over complicating this thing, can I get some help?

**JQUERY Javascript Table**

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 3849,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    pageList: [100, 200, 600, 1000],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'ID',
        title: 'ID',
        align: 'center',
        visible: false
    },{
        field: 'backlink',
        title: 'Backlink',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'indexed',
        title: 'PI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'dindexed',
        title: 'DI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'moz',
        title: 'MOZ',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'email',
        title: 'EM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'social',
        title: 'SOC+',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'whois',
        title: 'WHO',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'notes',
        title: 'NT',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'removed',
        title: 'RM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'import_label',
        title: 'SR',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'important',
        title: 'IM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'refresh',
        title: 'RF',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
        class: 'refreshstats'
    },{
        field: 'exempt',
        title: 'EX',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'spammy',
        title: 'SP',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    }]
});
```

**JQUERY**

```
if ($('tbody tr td:nth-child(14)').has('input:checkbox:checked')) {
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('spammy_color');
}
```

**Before HTML**

```
<tbody class="searchable">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**After HTML**

```
<tbody class="searchable">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td class="spammy_color"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td class="spammy_color"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td class="spammy_color"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
<td class="spammy_color"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You can slightly reduce that to `$('tbody tr td:nth-child(14) input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` I think

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
if ($('.searchable td:nth-child(14):has(:checked)')) {
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('spammy_color');
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z743a3md/3/)

Comment: does not seem to be working, I edited my HTML to match exactly what I have.

Comment: @CesarBielich, just updated my fiddle. Make sure you have tbody wrapped in table. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Dang still not working, it seems to have to do with my table being generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you need something like this:

1. get checked checkboxes
2. get parents
3. add class

```js
$('tr td:nth-child(14) :checked').parent().addClass('spm');
```

```css
.spm {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="searchable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:** i'm a bit look to `bootstrapTable` plugin and methinks you bit rushed with the choice.
Anyway in [examples page](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/#style-cellstyle) you can find sample with `CellStyle`

> Use cellStyle column option to set the cell style of bootstrap table

and your `cellStyle` function should be like

```
function cellstyle(value, row, index){
    if(value){
        return {
            classes: "spammy_color"
        };
    }
    return {};
}
```

Comment: ok your example works with my JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/j490azj8/1/ but for some reason is not working on my site. I have to add which I am sorry I didn't that this table is dynamically generated through javascript so I have a feeling that is the issue

Comment: @CesarBielich, so provide what you have, and we can help you

Comment: I have added my JS code that generates the table as well. The HTML is exactly what it looks like after it is generated

Comment: @CesarBielich, what is plugin `bootstrapTable`?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry about that

Comment: @CesarBielich can you provide sample data for table? in json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78251/discussion-between-grundy-and-cesar-bielich).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer. The issue is when trying to apply styling and things like that to a dynamically generated table like `datatable` or `bootstrapTable` you have to wait till the data is fully loaded first or it will not apply the styling through jquery.

My Code that works

```
$table.on('load-success.bs.table', function () {
    $('tr td:nth-child(14) :checked').parent().addClass('spammy_color');
});
```

[bootstrapTable Events Documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)