# wait till bootstrapTable is fully loaded before doing something

Tags: jquery

I have a javascript based bootstrapTable that dynamically generates the table and data.

I am having an issue trying to apply some CSS styling and classes to some of the `td`'s that are being generated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334141/using-nth-child-and-has#30334753). I have realized that I think my problem is that the table is not fully loaded which is causing my code not to work. It works fine if I manually write the table code, but not dynamically.

I tried using the `load` event to wait for the table to load but that seems to not work

```
$table.load(function() {
// do something
});
```

What jquery do I need to in order to wait for `$table` to be fully loaded before I do something?

**javascript table**

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 3849,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    pageList: [100, 200, 600, 1000],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'ID',
        title: 'ID',
        align: 'center',
        visible: false
    },{
        field: 'backlink',
        title: 'Backlink',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'indexed',
        title: 'PI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'dindexed',
        title: 'DI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'moz',
        title: 'MOZ',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'email',
        title: 'EM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'social',
        title: 'SOC+',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'whois',
        title: 'WHO',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'notes',
        title: 'NT',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'removed',
        title: 'RM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'import_label',
        title: 'SR',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'important',
        title: 'IM',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'refresh',
        title: 'RF',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
        class: 'refreshstats'
    },{
        field: 'exempt',
        title: 'EX',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'spammy',
        title: 'SP',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    }]
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: I have and unless you see something I don't I cant find anything.

Comment: OMG right after I write my comment I find it lol `$table.on('load-success.bs.table', function () {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many events you can override:

```
    onAll: function (name, args) {
        return false;
    },
    onClickRow: function (item, $element) {
        return false;
    },
    onDblClickRow: function (item, $element) {
        return false;
    },
    onSort: function (name, order) {
        return false;
    },
    onCheck: function (row) {
        return false;
    },
    onUncheck: function (row) {
        return false;
    },
    onCheckAll: function () {
        return false;
    },
    onUncheckAll: function () {
        return false;
    },
    onLoadSuccess: function (data) {
        return false;
    },
    onLoadError: function (status) {
        return false;
    },
    onColumnSwitch: function (field, checked) {
        return false;
    },
    onPageChange: function (number, size) {
        return false;
    },
    onSearch: function (text) {
        return false;
    },
    onToggle: function (cardView) {
        return false;
    },
    onPreBody: function (data) {
        return false;
    },
    onPostBody: function () {
        return false;
    },
    onPostHeader: function () {
        return false;
    },
    onPreRows: function () {
        return false;
    },
    onPostRows: function () {
        return false;
    }
```

Knowing nothing about how this plugin works, I would suggest trying the `onLoadSuccess` or `onPostRows`:

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    ...
    onLoadSuccess: function() {
        // do something
    },
    ...
 });
```

Comment: I found the answer right after I commented lol yeah this is it `$table.on('load-success.bs.table', function () {`

Comment: Be careful with that approach -- those internal event names could change in future versions of the plugin, whereas the API events shouldn't.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, what about arguments of onLoadSuccess function?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
                console.log('load-success');
            })
```

Of course, before the on, have your `bootstrapTable` call like it was
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#table-events

Comment: this has unwanted repercussions on formatted rows with ajax calls. Ex: if you have a select control on a formatted row, and on change you'd want to save its value, it will save the value of each row and not just the one you changed because of this event.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs there is a `onLoadSuccess` event that fires after the data successfully loads.

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 3849,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    pageList: [100, 200, 600, 1000],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    onLoadSuccess: function(){
      //do something after data has loaded
    },
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned the `onLoadSuccess` (`load-success.bs.table`) event will be triggered when the data is loaded successfully.

Alternatively the `onPostBody` (`post-body.bs.table`) event can be used. It will be triggered after the table body is rendered and available in the DOM.

A full list of events can be is available in [events.md](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/dea698b3b1aa98d0b5a5752f4001efa4186bde9a/site/docs/api/events.md)

Comment: You shouldn't directly paste the link of a branch so that the link will be invalid after the variation; you have to find the name of the sha1 and paste it with the link of the sha1, then there will be no problem. Anyway, I hope you can update the link, and thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

There are two ways to achieve this.

- One is to use the properties provided by BootstrapTable (the part in red in the image below)

  ```js
  $('#TableID').bootstrapTable({
       // ...
      onLoadSuccess: function() {
          // ...
    },
  })
  ```
- The other uses JS (the part in green in the image below)

---

#### JS

Focus on the **green** color

[image]

so you can try something like this

JS

```js
const TABLE_ID = "myTable";
const table = $(`#${TABLE_ID}`)
table.on('load-success.bs.table', function (event, rowArray) { // I prefer to call ``data`` as ``rowArray``.
  // alert(JSON.stringify(rowArray));
})

// another example
table.on('click-cell.bs.table', function (event, field, value, row, td) {
  td = td[0]
  // ...
})
```

[onClickCell | click-cell.bs.table](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onclickcell) ([backup link](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/0cee7c93572869280b4c52d8eb9f1056e2f92ac4/docs/api/events/index.html#L508))

HTML

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-blue"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-search="true"
       data-search-highlight="true"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-minimum-count-columns="2"
       data-show-pagination-switch="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-id-field="id"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
       data-show-footer="false"
       data-side-pagination="client"
       data-export-types='["csv", "json", "excel", "doc", "sql", "png"]'
       data-editable = '[false, true, false, false]'
       data-export-options='{
        "fileName": "products"
        }'
       data-url="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="id">Id</th>
    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="title">Title</th>
    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="url">URL</th>
    <th data-sortable="true" data-formatter="imageFormatter" data-field="thumbnailUrl">Thumbnail URL</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

### Doc

Please refer to the useful documents

> https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onloadsuccess

If the link not working in the future, then please refer to

> [wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/gh-pages/0cee7c935/docs/api/events](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/0cee7c93572869280b4c52d8eb9f1056e2f92ac4/docs/api/events/index.html#L677-L681)

Comment: If you want to see a full example, you can refer to my other article( [How to make HTML table cell editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67177133) )